# How to design an Ecto changeset as a true before_save callback

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I've a simple before_save transformation and learned that phoenix uses Ecto changest for this task.

My `Stage` model has a `position` attribute which defaults to the `current maximum + 1` so tried to implement this as follows:

**Stage Model:**

```
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
    |> validate_required([:name])
    |> set_position
  end

  defp set_position(current_changeset) do
    # get current max position from db
    max_position = Repo.one(
      from s in Stage,
      select: fragment("COALESCE(MAX(?),0)", s.position)
    )

    case current_changeset do
      %Ecto.Changeset{valid?: true} -> 
        put_change(current_changeset, :position, max_position+1)
      _ ->
        current_changeset
    end
  end
```

Which works fine when inserting one by one records but fails in bulk insertion; for example in below `seed` file.

**Seed**

```
alias MyApp.{Repo, Post}

[
  %{name: "Requirements"},
  %{name: "Quotation"},
  %{name: "Development"},
  %{name: "Closing"}
] 
|> Enum.map(&Post.changeset(%Post{}, &1)) 
|> Enum.each(&Repo.insert!(&1))
```

**Expected/Current Behavior:**

If current max position is say `7`, for all inserted 4 records above, position will be set to `8` instead of `8,9,10,11` respectively! That's because the first pipe will prepare all changests then insert them!

Is the way i am seeding wrong? or the changeset? How can i re-design this so the behavior is the same regardless of how i do insertions? any feedback to improve how i am doing it is appreciated!

Comment: I haven't tried this but does changing `|> set_position` to `|> prepare_changes(&set_position/1)` work? That should run `set_position` in a Database Transaction when the record is inserted.

Comment: Using one Enum pass should fix the issue I think:
`[%{name: "Requirements"}, %{name: "Quotation"}, %{name: "Development"}, %{name: "Closing"}] |> Enum.each(&Post.changeset(%Post{}, &1) |> &Repo.insert!)`

Comment: @Dogbert yes, this works nicely! thanks. Newbie question what the /1 means, is it the elxir number of args? then why it causes exception without it? plz post an answer to accept.

Comment: @AbM you are right, but i wanted to make the changest able to handle anyway i insert records!

Comment: @Nimir Yes, number of arguments. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778114/what-does-the-slash-notation-in-elixir-mean. That value is required even if the function takes 0 arguments. `&foo` is not valid syntax in Elixir.

Comment: @Dogbert so for anonymous func in elixir the arity is mandatory?

Comment: @Nimir to convert a named function to an anonymous function yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Ecto.Changeset.prepare_changes/2` to run arbitrary computation inside the database transaction of that changeset. Your `set_position/1` function has the correct argument/return value (changeset -> changeset), so you just need to change:

```
|> set_position
```

to

```
|> prepare_changes(&set_position/1)
```

and `set_position` will now be executed in the same transaction as and just before your Post is inserted, instead of being executed while the changeset is created.